# replace url path htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a question about redirecting old page paths in .htaccess.

Link https://www.yourwebsite.com/products/product.php?id=44352

need to redirect to
https://www.yourwebsite.com/product?id=44352

This means that the id must stay in the url, but remove /products folder and .php extension.

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products/product.php?type=?$ 

RewriteRule (.*) https://www.yourwebsite.com/product?type=$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?products/product.php$ https://example.com/product [R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I have it working now, but one question left:
RewriteRule ^/?products/product.php$

products/product.php?name=productname&date=2018

how do i remove ?name=productname

Comment: @ChrisAsparuhov How is that connected to the quesiton above? If it is a separate question the 1. try to find the answer yourself, especially since you now have a working example and 2. please post a separate question for a separate question.